# Traversing JSON in Python and return conditional results

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to traverse JSON in Python using the built in `json` package and return the data conditionally.

Here's a sample of the JSON:

```json
{
    "1605855600000":
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "1. Choice 1",
            "checked": true
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "2. Choice 2",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "3. Choice 3",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "value": "4. Choice 4",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "value": "5. Choice 5",
            "checked": false
        }
    ],
    "1604732400000":
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "1. Choice 1",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "2. Choice 2",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "3. Choice 3",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "value": "4. Choice 4",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "value": "5. Choice 5",
            "checked": false
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is check each record (the number is a date) for any true values and return a new JSON object with the date and the true values for that date. So for the example above, the output would look like:

```json
{
   "1605855600000":
   [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "1. Choice 1",
            "checked": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I am struggling to understand how to write the for loop to look through each date and only return the date and the values when they are true.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  "I am struggling" suggests that you need to search out appropriate documentation, or a local tutor -- not Stack Overflow.

Comment: That said, a simple search for "Python JSON" will bring you to the `json` package.  From there, you read the JSON file into a Python dict, and do your searching with the built-in tools you should already know.  We generally expect you to do such research before posting here ... but that should get you on the right track.

Comment: @Prune Maybe I should've clarified in the post but I'm not having any issues with using the json package, the issue is with the logic surrounding how to access the data appropriately, like the answer below. And if stack overflow isn't for "I'm struggling" then I don't think it would exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you load the json with the builtin json package.
then you will get a dict object. you can use iterate it with `.items()` to get the dates and the values.

then just filter the inner documents and if there are any left add it to a different dict.

like this:

```
data = """your json here"""
data = json.loads(data)
result = {}
for date, items in data.items():
    checked_items = list(filter(lambda x: x['checked'], items))
    if checked_items:
         result[date] = checked_items
json.dumps(result)
```